# property of continuous function

Tags: calculus

if $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow [a,b]$ is continuous and $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbf{R}^+$ then  there is some $c\in [a,b]$, $$f(c)=\dfrac {\alpha f(a)+\beta f(b)}{\alpha+\beta}.$$ Should I use Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: yes, yes you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality that $f(a)\leqslant f(b)$ and let $y$ be the expression $$y=\dfrac{\alpha f(a)+ \beta f(b)}{\alpha +\beta}.$$ Note that $$\dfrac{\alpha f(a)+ \beta f(b)}{\alpha +\beta}\leqslant \dfrac{\alpha f(b)+ \beta f(b)}{\alpha +\beta}=f(b)$$ and also $$\dfrac{\alpha f(a)+ \beta f(b)}{\alpha +\beta}\geqslant \dfrac{\alpha f(a)+ \beta f(a)}{\alpha +\beta}=f(a)$$ Then you have $f(a)\leqslant y \leqslant f(b)$ and since $f(a),f(b)\in [a,b]$ this means that $y\in [a,b]$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Yes, of course. The rest is resulted from intermediate value theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

${\alpha\over{\alpha +\beta}}f(a)+{\beta\over{\alpha+\beta}}f(b)$ is an element of the interval $[f(a),f(b)]$ if $f(a)<f(b)$ or $[f(b),f(a)]$ since the image of a connected set by a continuous map is connected, we deduce that the interval bounded by $f(a),f(b)$ is in the image of $f$.