# Is it true that there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=\frac{Af(a)+Bf(b)}{A+B}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

We have that $f$ is a continuous real function on $[a,b]$ and $A,B >0$.

I know that by the intermediate value theorem it must be true that there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$. Hence I'm wondering if the above result is true? I've trialed this by taking $f(x)=x$ and it seems to work for this function. How could this be proved/disproved?

Comment: I take it you mean $\forall A,B \text{ } \exists c$?

Comment: @Acccumulation yes sorry, "$\forall A,B>0$, does there exist $c \in [a,b]$ ...."

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498787/property-of-continuous-function

Answer (score 2):

You know that the image of an interval under a continuous function is an interval, and hence convex (intermediate value theorem). What you are doing on the right hand side is taking a convex combination of two elements of the image of $[a,b]$ under $f$. Hence, there exists such a $c$.